# Service Accounts with Azure AD Modern Authentication

Tags: entra-id

Referring to the below article, Microsoft is disabling the Basic authentication on azure AD, then how we can run the service accounts smoothly? because services accounts are working on basic authentication with Azure AD.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/block-legacy-authentication

Comment: The service will need to be modified to use token-based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts can use OAuth token-based authentication or certificate-based authentication for connecting to Azure AD and related services with the Graph API.

Please note: Microsoft isn't [yet] disabling basic auth across *all* service endpoints, but they *are* recommending that customers stop using basic auth and disable it. Per the document, "[Deprecation of Basic authentication in Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online#what-we-are-changing),"

> We're removing the ability to use Basic authentication in Exchange
> Online for Exchange ActiveSync (EAS), POP, IMAP, Remote PowerShell,
> Exchange Web Services (EWS), Offline Address Book (OAB), Outlook for
> Windows, and Mac.
>
> We're also disabling SMTP AUTH in all tenants in which it's not being
> used.

If you're using an on-premises service account to access Azure AD, you will need to configure a specific scope of delegated permissions for that identity. You can begin this by logging into the Azure AD portal and going to Enterprise Applications. Create a new application (this can even be used if your "application" is a PowerShell script). After creating the application registration, you'll need to configure the clients and secrets tab for the kind of authentication that you want to use, then configure the API permissions to scope it to the specific permissions that your application needs.